# Android Studio can't debug if I use C code

Tags: android, c, android-studio, debugging, java-native-interface

Android Studio can't start the debugger if I use C code though JNI.
Running it normally works well, but the debugger doesn't even start, regardless if I'm debugging Kotlin or C code.

It throws a message `Debugger process finished with exit code 127. Rerun 'app'`
And the only detail it gave me is `com.intellij.execution.ExecutionFinishedException: Execution finished`.

Here I set up a simple github repository to replicate the error: https://github.com/perojas3/Android-JNI-debug-bug-example. It simply calls C code to get a string and then displays it in a toast.

And here I set up an small youtube video displaying the bug the way it is happening: https://youtu.be/8jIL5yqP7m8

I'm using Manjaro Linux right now.

Comment: I'm having the same problem. I think it happened after upgrading to Android Studio 4.2. What version do you have?

Comment: I'm using android-studio 4.2.1.0-1. I will try downgrading,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I also had this issue.
I was able to run and debug my code normally, but for some reason I started to get this crash while running on debugging mode:

> Debugger process finished with exit code 127

After playing a lot with Android Studio's settings and Edit Configurations, clearing caches, restarting both Android Studio and the computer and many other things, nothing was helpful.

I struggled with it a lot and the fact that there're no discussions anywhere about it annoyed me a lot, so having no information online together with the previous feeling about it happening after upgrading to Android Studio 4.2, made me think maybe it's a new issue raised in Android Studio's new 4.2 version.

So, I decided to download Android Studio 4.1.3 and give it a try. It worked like a magic and I can finally debug my code :)

Comment: This actually solved the problem. Thanks.

Answer (score 7):

I had the same issue and installing `libncurses5` package solved it.

If using Ubuntu: `sudo apt install libncurses5` and launch the debugger again (no android studio restart required).

Comment: Had the same problem, your advice helped! How did you figure it ?

Comment: Looked for install dependencies for Android Studio and saw it listed somewhere.